# Writing to SQL table when Azure Log Analytics is getting a new row

Tags: sql, azure, logging, triggers, analytics

Hello good people over the internet, I need your wisdom.
I want to write to SQL table some results from Azure Log Analytics, I couldn't find an answer but is there any option to trigger a function or a procedure when new row is written to the logs?
Also is there any filter option for example only row with a specific values will trigger that function/procedure?
Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve but if you what something like DDL events captured. You can go to Log Analytics Workspace then Logs and write a KQL query to select data you need, and then create a new alert rule.

```
AzureDiagnostics //table where all audits are stored
| where Category == "SQLSecurityAuditEvents" 
| where statement_s has "alter user" //SWAP STRING YOU WANT TO SEARCH IN STATEMENTS(QUERY)
| where statement_s !has "alter table" //SWAP STRING YOU DO NOT WANT TO SEARCH IN STATEMENTS(QUERY)
| where database_principal_name_s != "DB_USER" //EXCLUDE SINGLE USER
```